# How to add overview window on openstreet map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, leaflet

I'd like to implement map quality tool,
i am using open street map and leaflet JavaScript  for rendering map,

i want to implement overview window on bottom left corner of map like in Google map,

any one suggest me any solution from past experience ?

i am using this environment : ruby 2.0.0 and rails 4.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with this leaflet plugin MiniMap: https://github.com/Norkart/Leaflet-MiniMap

In my opinion, it is not as good as GoogleMap overview map and there are a few bugs.

However, it is a good start

Comment: I am finding this only, thanks a lot. this is very help full.